# I don't understand why my array produces output I can't use

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to create list of computers which I can work on using Get-Computer.
Here are two ways to create the list.
I don’t understand why they are different or how I can get the results of the two methods to have the same value.

My code is:

```
    $ComputerList1 = "WS7-HUR-MANAGER","WS7-HUR-NURSE"
    $ComputerList2 = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "WS7-HUR*"} | Select`   Name
    Get-Variable ComputerList1 | Select Name, Value
    Get-Variable ComputerList2 | Select Name, Value
```

The output:

```
Name              Value                                           
----              -----                                           
ComputerList1     {WS7-HUR-MANAGER, WS7-HUR-NURSE}                
ComputerList2     {@{Name=WS7-HUR-MANAGER}, @{Name=WS7-HUR-NURSE}}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$ComputerList1` contains contains a string array object.
`$ComputerList2` contains a custom PowerShell object that was returned by Get-ADComputer and then filtered to only include it's `Name` property.

You can see the difference between the two by piping each to Get-Member.

```
$ComputerList1 | Get-Member
$ComputerList2 | Get-Member
```

Per the other answer you can use the `-ExpandProperty` switch of the `Select-Object` cmdlet to take one property of the object and return its contents as a new object of it's type. E.g if the property contained a string, you would then get a string object. E.g:

```
 $ComputerList2 = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "WS7-HUR*"} | Select ExpandProperty Name
```

Or you can also do this to access the property directly and assign it to a variable:

```
$ComputerList2 = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "WS7-HUR*"}).Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ComputerList2 = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "WS7-HUR*"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Thanks, guys.  You were wonderful.  After 3 days of research you solved my problem in just a few minutes.  Kudos.